# unable to fetch data from json API wordpress throught AngularJS + Onsen

Tags: json, angularjs, wordpress, onsen-ui

I am trying to get data from json API, i am using onsen-ui for creating phonegap app. I am using wordpress plugin to get that. 
Here is how i am trying to do this.

```
module.factory('$data', function($http) {
      var data = {};


      $http.get('http://www.foduu.com/api/get_recent_posts').
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data.posts);
       // return data;
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("error in fetching data");
      });
  });
```

But this is what i am getting in the console.log.

[image]

In HTML i have coded similar to

```
<ons-list ng-controller="MasterController">
        <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="item" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="showDetail($index)">
          <ons-row>
            <ons-col width="60px"> 
              <div class="item-thum"></div>
            </ons-col>
            <ons-col>
              <header>
                <span class="item-title">{{item.title}}</span>
                <span class="item-label">{{item.label}}</span>
              </header>
              <p class="item-desc">{{item.desc}}</p>
            </ons-col>
          </ons-row>                          
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
```

Any suggestions on this will be really helpful.

Thank you

Comment: It's not a problem with the $http.get, it's that your factory is not built properly. A factory should have a return. Check out this tutorial: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/

Comment: Ok i understand. but how do i do then? I want to fetch data from my website.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing a `return`:

```
module.factory('$data', function($http) {
      var data = {};


      $http.get('http://www.foduu.com/api/get_recent_posts').
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data.posts);
       // return data;
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("error in fetching data");
      });

      return data;
});
```

As a side note, I suggest that you don't name your own services and factories with a `$` prefix.  This is an Angular convention for *its* own provided services.

Also, at the moment, this `factory` doesn't do much.  You should probably return the promise that `$http.get` returns you:

```
module.factory('$data', function($http) {
      var data = {

          getRecentPosts: function() {
              return $http.get('http://www.foduu.com/api/get_recent_posts');
          }
      };

      return data;
});
```

Then handle the promise `success` and `error` in the controller that references this factory.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.foduu.com/api/get_recent_posts. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: This is a different issue.  You are now facing a CORS problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your factory name should not begin with a $.

Here is an example of a factory that works for me

```
angular.module('appName')
  .factory('FactoryName', function ($http, $q) {

    return {
      myFunctionName: function (callback) {
        var cb = callback || angular.noop;
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('insertYourURLHere')
          .success(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
            return cb();
          }).
          error(function (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
            return cb(err);
          }.bind(this));

        return deferred.promise;
      },
        };
  });
```

Then you can call this in your controller:

```
$scope.variableName = FactoryName.getProjects()
      .then(function(data){
        $scope.variableName = data;
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        $log.error(err);
      });
```

Make sure you inject the FactoryName dependency in your controller.

Comment: If you are going to handle both the success and error in the controller, then there is no use creating a new promise with `$q.defer()`.  You are just calling directly through.

Comment: I hadn't thought about that. I've just been using this general design pattern, but you're right I could just handle it in the controller.